# Extracting image value from Array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues extracting a value from an array of images via Codeigniter/MySQL. So i have a table called "image" in my database and if i echo out it i get the following code:

```
{"f01efdf6fe3b2bb387d3094aa701203f":{"filename":"f01efdf6fe3b2bb387d3094aa701203f.jpg","alt":"","caption":"","primary":true},"b11581adadd1848acb2898e7a284afc1":{"filename":"b11581adadd1848acb2898e7a284afc1.png","alt":"","caption":""},"2cfee6d3c334696833b1cfe13910fcf1":{"filename":"2cfee6d3c334696833b1cfe13910fcf1.png","alt":"","caption":""}}
```

As you can see there are 3 images there, what i need is to echo out just the image where "primary" value is:true within a foreach loop...

EDIT:

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM offers_products WHERE offer_large LIMIT 5;");
?>

<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>

<li><a href="/<?=$row->slug?>"><?=$row->id?></a></li>
<li><?=$row->name?></li>
<li><!-- THIS IS THE IMAGES TABLE VALUE --> <?=$row->images?> <!-- --></li>
<li><?=$row->description?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$array = json_decode($stringFromDatabase, true);
$primary = false;
foreach ($array as $longStringDontCare => $imageArray) {
    if (!empty($imageArray['primary'])) {
       $primary = $imageArray;
       break;
    }
} 
if ($primary) {
   echo $primary['filename'];// should give: f01efdf6fe3b2bb387d3094aa701203f.jpg
}
```

To give you one last hint:

```
<?php
function getPrimaryImageFromJsonString($stringFromDatabase) {
    $array = json_decode($stringFromDatabase, true);
    $primary = false;
    foreach ($array as $longStringDontCare => $imageArray) {
        if (!empty($imageArray['primary'])) {
           $primary = $imageArray;
           break;
        }
    } 
    if ($primary) {
       return $primary['filename'];
    }
    return null;
}
?>


<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>

<li><a href="/<?=$row->slug?>"><?=$row->id?></a></li>
<li><?=$row->name?></li>
<li><?php echo getPrimaryImageFromJsonString($row->images);?></li>
<li><?=$row->description?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

L.E: a few edits.

Comment: I edited my question above as i have a foreach loop already, any idea ? ;)

Comment: you will need a second one to parse the json string into an array using the `json_encode` function. You can have nested `foreach` loops.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help, i really appreciate it. But, i'm still struggling as the "$stringFromDatabase" is actually within the foreach loop that i'm using "<?=$row->images?>" I added my full code above if you can give me one more example to work with. that would be very well appreciated, as i've never done this one before ;)... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first decode the json encoded string and extract the primary image from there:

Here is small function which you can use to extract the primary image:(You can place this function in Helper if you are using CodeIgniter)

```
function get_primary_image($encode_json_data)
{
    $primary_image = '';
    $decoded_json = json_decode($encode_json_data);
    foreach($decoded_json as $obj)
    {
        if(isset($obj->primary) && $obj->primary == 1)
            $primary_image = $obj->filename;
    }
    return $primary_image;
}
```

You can call above function in your view in following way:

```
<?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>

<li><a href="/<?=$row->slug?>"><?=$row->id?></a></li>
<li><?=$row->name?></li>
<li> <?=get_primary_image($row->images)?></li><!-- Here, you call above function -->
<li><?=$row->description?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am wondering how this got an upvote as it doesn't take into consideration the idea that the array key is a hash string and it's value is another array.

Comment: @Twisted1919 : I've tested above code and working fine....I don't know, What things do u want me to take into consideration?Please elaborate it more....